# WordPress showing title but not content of pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the ff: codes for my regular WordPress page under page.php:

```
<section id="content-wrapper">
    <div class="sqs-cart-dropzone"></div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="content-inner" data-content-field="main-content">
        <div class="sqs-layout sqs-grid-12 columns-12" data-type="page" data-updated-on="1456865486035" id="page-54821cc9e4b0ab9977bd33f7">
        <?php the_title( sprintf( '<h1><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a></h1>' ); ?>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
</section>
```

For some reason, this won't pull up the content of the pages. It's only showing up the title of the page but no content at all.

What am I missing?

What should I put on my page.php to make it all work out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are missing is the standard WordPress loop

```
<?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
      <?php the_title( sprintf( '<h1><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a></h1>' ); ?>
      <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

[Check](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)